# How to get first month of the year from TODAY Function in Excel?

Tags: excel

In a excel sheet range **A1:A12**, I need months like:

**Jan 2020** to **Dec 2020** for current year.

and **Jan 2021** to **Dec 2021** for next year. and so on. Automatically.

I google it but did not find any suitable result.

Plz help me and ignore my weak English and grammar.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you want the month as an actual date (in which case, which day) or as text? You will need the DATE function, YEAR and TODAY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want a real date, using the 1st of each month (you can then format the cells to just show *mmm yyyy* or whatever other format you like). In your first cell enter:

```
=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),ROWS($A$1:$A1),1)
```

and copy it down. If you actually want the month as text, just wrap that in the TEXT function:

```
=TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),ROWS($A$1:$A1),1),"mmm yyyy")
```

Note that the `DATE` function will happily adjust the year if you pass a month number greater than 12.

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula-

```
=TEXT(DATE(2020+INT(ROW()/13),MOD(ROW(),13)+INT(ROW()/13),1),"mmm-yyyy")
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To get This using `=TODAY()` function you have to use 2 cells.

Let's use A1 and B1 as the 2 cells.
In A1 you will display today's dat as dd/mm/yyyy

`=TODAY()` type this in A1

In B1 you will convert it to month and year.

`=TEXT(A1,"mmm-yyyy")` type this in B1

*But using this method you can only get this month.*